# When I call dequeueReusableCell(), TableView will instantiate my CustomCell and make it upcast to UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to understand how tableview works behind the scene.
When I call `dequeueReusableCell()`, `TableView` will instantiate my `CustomCell` to make a cell. It is something like that;

```
let cell = CustomCell(style: CustomCell.self, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell") // Cell type CustomCell.
```

and now we have a instance of cell. Everything is ok so far. But when I try to use this cell I have to downcast this cell to `CustomCell`.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

In the very above example `TableView` instantiated `CustomCELL` as type `CustomCELL` already. But it is actually type of `UITableCell`.

My question is that after `TableView` instantiated `CustomCell` as type of `CustomCell`, it makes `CustomCell` upcast to `UITableCell` so that the cell type become `UITableCell`? And I have to downcast it to `CustomCell` to use.

Can somebody explain me how all things works? 
Thanks your time!

```
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "CustomCell"

    // properties, etc., e.g.:
    private let label = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // here you do the setup, adding subviews, etc., e.g.:
        self.contentView.addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 8),
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -8),
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //other methods, e.g., for configuring the cell, e.g.:
    func configure(withTitle title: String) {
        label.text = title
    }

}
```

CustomTableController Class below

```
class CustomTableController: UITableViewController {

    fileprivate var data: [Model] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

        // registering a cell class for reuse is important
        // but it's enough to make it once in viewDidLoad
        tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier)

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // here you can dequeue your cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        // configure the cell using model, e.g.:
        cell.configure(withTitle: data[indexPath.row].title)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: `dequeueReusableCell` returns a `UITableViewCell` that is why you have to cast it to your custom cell `CustomCell`

Comment: I know it returns uıtablecell. My question how does it happrn when tableview instantiated mycustomclass :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function signature for `dequeueReusableCell` says that it returns an instance of `UITableViewCell?`
 so that is all that the compiler knows.

When you register your cell subclass against the reuse identifier, that function will actually return an instance of your cell subclass.

You then use the downcast operator `as` to let the compiler know that you are actually expecting an instance of your cell subclass at runtime. This will let you use the properties of your cell subclass.

If the downcast fails at runtime then you either get `nil` (for a conditional downcast `as?`) or an exception (for a forced downcast `as!`)

This behaviour relies on a fundamental concept in object-oriented programming; substitution. A subclass, S, of type T can be supplied to any function (or returned by any function) that is expecting or returns T.

Note that `cellForRowAt` is declared as returning `UITableViewCell` yet your are allowed to return your custom cell subclass instance.

Comment: So when ı register customcell, tableview instantiated my custom cell as type customcell but dequereReusableCell returns it as UITableViewCell because of return type you mean?

Comment: It returned the cell object which is an instance of your subclass, but the Swift compiler doesn't "know" this because that happens at runtime, not at compile time. At compile time all it knows is the return type of the function, which is `UITableViewCell`.  Since Swift is strongly types you need to downcast to tell the compiler what is happening

Comment: Thank you. I understand now . This last comment is great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `UITableView` upcasts the cell to `UITableViewCell` when returning is simply because Objective-C doesn't have generics, so this the only way to have a common interface for the `DataSource` methods.

But of course, with Swift we can use the power of generics to do what you want. The following extension will enable you to get the cell as a `CustomCell` from `UITableView`:

```
extension UITableView {
    func dequeueCell<T: UITableViewCell>(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> T? {
        return dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? T
    }
}

let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier)!
```

Comment: Your answer is also awesome. Thank you. Hope everyone reads this too.